# Hadoop Distcp aborting when copying data from one cluster to another

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, bigdata, distcp

I am trying to copy data of a partitioned Hive table from one cluster to another.
I am using distcp to copy the data but the data underlying data is of a partitioned hive table. 
I used the following command.

```
hadoop distcp -i {src} {tgt}
```

But as the  table was partitioned the directory structure was created according to the partitioned tables. So it is showing error creating duplicates and aborting job.

> org.apache.hadoop.toolsCopyListing$DulicateFileException: File would cause duplicates. Aborting

I also used `-skipcrccheck` `-update` `-overwrite` but none worked.

How to copy the data of a table from partitioned file path to destination?

Comment: Did u found  solution for same?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this option **-strategy dynamic**
By default distcp is using uniformsize.

Comment: This also gives duplicate files exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below settings to see if they are false.Set them to true.

```
hive> set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories;
hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=false
hive> set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive;
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive=false
```

Comment: What does Hive have to do with an (file-based) hadoop distcp?

Answer (score 0):

hadoop distcp -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=20480 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx15360m -Dipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true -Ddfs.checksum.type=CRC32C -m 500 \
-pb -update -delete {src} {target}

Comment: Please collaborate on what it actually does

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there can't be same file names. So, what's happening in your case is you trying to copy partitioned table from one cluster to other. And, 2 different named partitions have same file name.

Your solution is to correct Source path `{src}` in your command, such that you provide path uptil partitioned sub directory not the file.

For ex - Refer below :

```
/a/partcol=1/file1.txt
/a/partcol=2/file1.txt
```

If you use `{src}` as `"/a/*/*"` then you will get the error `"File would cause duplicates."`

But, if you use `{src}` as `"/a"` then you will not get error in copying.